# Selfmate In How Few? #1

Tags: chess, optimization, selfmate

Here's a new idea that I had. Instead of giving you the number of moves, you must find it yourself! Of course, the problems must be clear and concise. Now, let's get started!

For the first one, here is a problem that I composed, originally published on SuperProblem.ru on 8/22/2020. Enjoy!

**White Selfmates In How Many Moves?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> 1. Nb6 b1=Q 2. Ra8 (threat Rxd8) Qa1+ 3. Rxa1 c1=Q 4. Ra8 Qa1+ 5. Rxa1 etc and eventually selfmate in 17 after Black plays Nf7-d8

Very nice problem!

Comment: You seem very certain about this being the shortest possible line.

Comment: Nice job! How'd you solve it?

Comment: @RewanDemontay my first thought was Black wants to untangle with Nxc6 and Kd7, but White can muck that up with Nb6 and Ra8. I then worked out Black can delay with each pawn on the 2nd rank increasing the solution by 2 moves. I'm not sure how one would go about proving 17 moves is the minimum however.

Comment: @happystar You already provided the answer: proof is of no concern as the answer IS the proof.