# Selfmate In How Few? #2-Taking Flight

Tags: chess, optimization, selfmate

After my [first one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/105714/selfmate-in-how-few-1) was solved so quickly, it's time for the next meal! It's another one that I created for the same mentioned site. *Warning*: this is a fairly long one, even with its simple strategy!

Me, SuperProblem.ru on 4/7/2020, After Andrej Borodulin

**White Selfmates In How Many Moves?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Thanks to @retudin for pointing in comments to the subtelty I was missing before*

White selfmates in

> 24 moves.

The plan is pretty straightforward :

> White plays only the king while Black marks time with Kd5-d6-d5, captures Pc3, captures Pg5, go to e4, restricts the bK by playing c4, force Black by zugzwang to play ...g5 and ...Bg6#.

So:

> 1.Kh2 Kd5 ... 9.Kb3 Kd5 10.Kxc3 Kd6 ... 20.Kh6 Kd6 21.Kxg5 Kd5 22.c4! Kd6 23.Kf4 g5 24.Ke4 Bg6#

This nice problem is crystal-clear, with no dual and no way to change to move order.

Comment: with delay Kxc3 : 24 c4